# Show that the exponentials $1, e^{2\pi ix}, \dots , e^{2\pi ikx}, \dots$ form the basis for trigonometric polynomials.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, trigonometric-series

The exponentials $1, e^{2\pi ix}, \dots , e^{2\pi ikx}, \dots$ form the basis for trigonometric polynomials.

I know that from these we get $\cos{2\pi kx}$ and $\sin {2\pi kx}, k\in \mathbb{Z}$, but how can we get functions $\cos nx$ and $\sin nx$ from these?

I need this fact for the following proof from Stein and Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: They form a Schauder basis for functions of period 1.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you tell me why the fact that the lemma holds for all of these functions imply that the lemma is true for all trigonometric polynomials? I don't understand this point. Aren't we considering trigonometric polynomials of the form $\sum_{n=-N}^{n=N} c_n e^{inx}$ here?

Comment: Are you asking about Step 2?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes that is where I need the basis result, I think.

Comment: They mean all trigonometric polynomials of period one (or, whose period divides one). Denseness comes from Stone Weierstraẞ.

Comment: @takecare The trigonometric polynomials that you refer to (those generated by $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(nx)$) have period $2\pi$. But those in the theorem have period one. Thus, yours do not play a role in the theorem.